# Is it possible to store page_size into an object with static storage duration?

Tags: c, posix, page-size

We can extract page_size at runtime via `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. My first intention was to put this value on program startup into an object with static storage duration. So my intention was to declare some `extern` variable in a file scope as follows

```
extern const size_t page_size;
```

But when I try to define it somewhere else in a file scope as

```
const size_t page_size = (const size_t) sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
```

it does not compile. And that seems to be clear since `6.7.9(p4)`:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

I would not like to call the `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` any time I need a page size. Is there some workaround for that or what is the common solution?

Comment: This is the syntax for the `sysconf()` function: `long sysconf(int name);`  Note that the returned value is a `long`, not a `const size_t`

Comment: @user3629249 The returned value actually got me confused. Is there any reason they returned `long` instead of `size_t`. Or we should make an assumption that the `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` can be safely cast to `size_t`?

Comment: Im not privy to what the writers of the OS were thinking so I cannot tell you why they chose a signed value `long` rather than an unsigned value like `size_t`  However, it could be because `sysconf()` might return some negative values for other configuration parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` is a function call. It will always return the same value, but it is still a function call, so it cannot be used to initialize a global variable in C.

If you wanted to avoid calling that function repeatedly, you could declare the global variable as non-`const`, and assign its value during application startup.

Comment: I have a question. Would it look naturally if I put `extern const size_t page_size` into some header file and then simply define it in the translation unit in `main` function with file scope as `size_t page_size`?